# Problema com "else if" e "<" ">" no VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, condição

Estou montando um pequeno sistema que se o numero inserido no `textbox3` for menor que 3, apareça no `textbox4` uma mensagem "8%", e se for um numero entre 4 e 6, apareça no `textbox4` "9%". Essa parte do entre 4 e 6 não estou conseguindo fazer, tentei colocar:

```
textbox3.text > "4" and < "6"...
```

mas não deu certo. Aqui esta meu código.

```
If Val(TextBox3.Text < "3") Then
        TextBox4.Text = "8%"
    ElseIf Val(TextBox3.Text > "6") Then
        TextBox4.Text = "9%"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é para funcionar se só permitir 1 dígito, se permitir mais que 1 pode dar problema. O enunciado parece errado também, eu fiz o que estava escrito na pergunta. Parece ter um erro de lógica também, a não ser que tenha uma validação que eu não vi.

```
If TextBox3.Text < "3" Then
    TextBox4.Text = "8%"
ElseIf TextBox3.Text >= "4" AndAlso TextBox3.Text <= "6" Then
    TextBox4.Text = "9%"
End If
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/AndAlso.vb).

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Valeu!!!